# How to convert an ASCII file (with lat,lon coordinates) to a shapefile using OGR?

Tags: ogr, ogr2ogr, ascii, bash, ogrinfo

I have an ASCII file with the following columns : ID, longitude, latitude, value

Is it possible to use OGR (ogr2ogr or ogrinfo) in command line in order to open the ASCII file and convert it to a shapefile (in WGS84) using the point coordinates (X field=longtitude, Y field=latitude) ?

What I want to do is similar with what QGIS does when opening an ascii file with "Delimited Text" and defining the geometry (point coordinates).

I want to do that for a high number of files so I want to know if this is possible in OGR.

I finally tried the following:

```
ogr2ogr -f "ESRI Shapefile" test.shp input.csv -oo X_POSSIBLE_NAMES=lon -oo Y_POSSIBLE_NAMES=lat -oo KEEP_GEOM_COLUMNS=NO
```

but I get an error 
Unable to open datasource test.shp with the following drivers

Comment: You need a wildcard after =lon such as =lon*, or you can include the full column name, X_POSSIBLE_NAMES=longitude

Answer (score 3):

What you have is basically comma-separated values, so you can use GDAL's csv driver. You can find its documentation at https://www.gdal.org/drv_csv.html , see especially the section "Building point geometries".

Comment: thank you, I tried what you suggested (see the edited question) but with no success. Is this possible with shapefiles or only for kml ?